# Could not load file or assembly System.ComponentModel.Primitives

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, .net-framework-version

I've upgraded a project from .NET Framework 4.6 to .NET6 and now I'm getting this error:

```
'Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context.'
```

I've installed the latest version of `System.ComponentModel.Primitives` from Nuget but was surprised to see it's only 4.3.0.

I then added a binding redirect in app.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

But it still didn't help. The error persists. What is the real problem here?

Comment: have you checked this? add this to the csproj file, it might help. 

<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>

Comment: Added this now but the error persists.

Comment: You don't need to add the NuGet package, `System.ComponentModel.Primitives` is included with .NET. It's current version is 7.0. I suspect it's something else, you need to turn on [fusion logging](https://github.com/awaescher/Fusion) to see what the real assembly loading error is.